# Linux - Delete all files with extension that aren't listed in a control file?

Tags: bash

I want do delete all files with a specific extension (.xsl) whose names are *not* contained in another file. That is, if I have a file like

```
a.xsl
b.xsl
c.xsl
```

And a directory structure like

```
./a.xsl
./d.xsl
./folder1/b.xsl
./folder1/folder2/c.xsl
./folder1/folder2/e.xsl
```

I want to be able to delete `d.xsl` and `e.xsl`, but not `a.xsl`, `b.xsl`, or `c.xsl`. Target shell is BASH.

Comment: You might want to post this on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (Not tested):

```
for fn in $(find -type f -name '*.xsl')
do
  echo ${fn##*/} | grep -vf file1 >/dev/null && rm $fn
done
```

where file1 is the file containing the list of file entries.

`${fn##*/}` This removes everything till the last slash giving the filename alone. This is `grep`ped against the file and if not resent, deleted.

Comment: not tested either, but pretty sure the echo part is not it ... maybe the same for loop with `grep -v "${fn##*/}" file && rm "$fn"`

Answer (score 0):

This command will do it:

```
find -type f -name '*.xsl' -exec bash -c \
    'BN=`basename {}`; [[ -z `grep $BN used_xsl` ]] && svn rm {}' \;
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it? That seems a rather inefficient/roundabout way of doing what I want...

Answer (score 0):

If your path names won't have spaces in them, then you can use `fgrep` or `grep -F` to do the task neatly:

```
find . -name '*.xsl' -print | grep -F -v -f excluded.files | xargs rm -f
```

If you might have to deal with arbitrary pathnames (newlines, spaces, etc), then you have to work harder.